# Changing the receiving Wifi channel on my computer. I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop running Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I live full time in a motor home, and almost always in a RV park. The wifi in these parks is usually very slow, over-crowded, and pretty inadequate at best. I have the "Wifi Monitor" app loaded on my laptop, so I can monitor the local free signals. I also use my phone as a hotspot but limit that because it eats through my data quickly.

My question: Wifi Monitor often suggests other wifi channels that would work better with the incoming wifi signal from the RV parks. I have not been able to find in my laptop's software the place where I can change those wifi channels. Also, I can not seem to find information on-line for my situation, that does not assume I am using a router.

Comment: You do not need to change the channels, Windows searches all automaically

Comment: You don’t select the “receiving channel”. The Access Point that “owns” the network broadcasts on a set channel.

Comment: If you don't want "auto", you have to log in to the *modem/router* to specify a channel (that's not much help if you're accessing someone else's free wifi, admittedly).

Comment: Wi-Fi channels are equivalent with different ranges of emitted signal's frequency. Unless you are using your laptop as a hotspot, you can't specify your wifi channel, because you don't emit anything. Instead, you can specify a wireless-router's channel.

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite how it works - you set the frequency  *on the router* and you can't change it on your client.

Your current situation is *roughly* the worst possible for wireless - you have walls of metal, and no line of sight. You might want to use a wireless monitor type application in *another* way - get a USB extender and an *external* wireless adapter, and stick it out your window(s) or roof to see where you get the best reception. You might even consider the [classic cantenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantenna), or a adapter with a better, high gain antenna.

Comment: All good answers, and I appreciate the time taken to do so. To be honest the signal strength is not the problem. It's always quite good. I think the problem is mostly due to the limited amount of bandwidth in these parks. I notice that I have less issues early in the morning or late at night, probably because most people are not online.